# Python printing a variable

Tags: python

Below is what Im getting when I print

```
executionId = str(thread_ts)

print (executionId)
```

Output:

```
('1608571839.008600',)
```

How can I just get the value without ('',)  i.e 1608571839.008600

Comment: `executionId[0]`

Comment: @jakub `executionId[0]` would be the character `'('`.

Comment: oops, thanks. that should be `thread_ts[0]` as the accepted answer shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `thread_ts` is a `tuple`?

```
>>> str((1608571839.008600,))

'(1608571839.008600,)'
```

So either index the value:

```
thread_ts = (1608571839.008600,)
executionId = thread_ts[0] 
print(executionId) # or print(str(executionId))
```

Or unpack:

```
thread_ts = (1608571839.008600,)
executionId = thread_ts
print(*executionId) # or print(str(*executionId))
```

I add the `str` calls if you actually wanted to explicitly convert to `str` type, but for printing numbers that is not really necessary.

Also, note the difference between the two approaches.  In the first example, `executionId` is a number `executionId ---> 1608571839.008600`, while in the second, `executionId` is still a `tuple` `executionId ---> (1608571839.008600,)`